# Handling Notification Actions when the application is killed iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I working on both local and remote notifications for iOS on an application and im facing an issue. When the app is killed and a notification arrives either remote or local and I click on the notification then as learnt didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called and the application opens. But if I select a custom action instead of clicking on the notification my application crashes.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

setActions()
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.badge,.sound], completionHandler: {(granted,error) in
        if granted{
            print("Notification access granted")
        }
        else
        {
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        }
    })
}
else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
} else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
}
registerForPushNotifications(application: application)

if let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [String: AnyObject]
{
self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: notification)
}

return true
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
let aps = data["aps"] as! [String:AnyObject]
let alert = aps["alert"] as! [String:AnyObject]
let title = alert["title"] as! String
let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(10)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
        let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        let activeViewCont = navigationController.viewControllers
        let viewController  = activeViewCont[0] as? ViewController
        viewController?.button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)

}
print("Push notification received: \(data)")
}


func setActions(){

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

        let like = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "like", title: "Like", options: .foreground)

        let dismiss = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "dismiss", title: "Dismiss", options: .destructive)


        //Action for CHAT REPLY
        let reply = UNTextInputNotificationAction(identifier: "reply", title: "Reply", options: .foreground, textInputButtonTitle: "Send", textInputPlaceholder: "Enter Your Message")

        let categoryOne = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "customNotification", actions: [like,dismiss,reply], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
        let categoryTwo = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "localNotification", actions: [like,dismiss], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([categoryOne,categoryTwo])
    }
    else
    {
        let like = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()

        like.activationMode = .foreground
        like.identifier = "like"
        like.title = "Like"


        let dismiss = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
        dismiss.activationMode = .background
        dismiss.identifier = "dismiss"
        dismiss.title = "Dismiss"

        let reply = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
        reply.activationMode = .background
        reply.identifier = "reply"
        reply.title = "Reply"
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            reply.behavior = .textInput
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

        let categoryOne = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
        categoryOne.identifier = "customNotification"
        categoryOne.setActions([dismiss,like,reply], for: .default)

        let categoryTwo = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
        categoryTwo.identifier = "localNotification"
        categoryTwo.setActions([dismiss], for: .default)

        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: [categoryOne,categoryTwo])

        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show `setActions`.

Comment: I have updated the question by adding setActions

Comment: I answered the same question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/43815251/3934111

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use this code inside dispatch queue.

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var homeViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController)
appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = nav
```

Comment: When a notification arrives when the app is killed only didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called so how does this solve my issue

Comment: Your application is crashing because of you are creating viewcontroller object normally not from storyboard identifier. You were created navigation controller object, at that time there is no viewcontrollers set into navigation controller stack because of that reason.